# C++ wxWidgets - how to centre toolbar icons using wxToolbar on Windows?

Tags: windows, c++11, wxwidgets, cross-compiling

I've finally managed my cross compiler options to compile my wxWidgets app. That's simple app for my friend - it symulates dices (he want to use it to play RPG games).
However, the problem is with the toolbar. The code used:

```
//After adding elements,  binding with events and so on
m_pToolbar->InsertStretchableSpace(0);
m_pToolbar->InsertStretchableSpace(4);
```

And the result on linux...
[image: linux]

And using wine(the same on Virtual XP on VirtualBox):
[image: win1]

[image: win2]

Could anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lack of the space on top of the toolbar under MSW looks like a bug, if it's still not fixed in the latest wxWidgets version (from svn or Github), please [report it](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/newticket).

You can work around it by positioning the toolbar itself manually inside a sizer and centring it vertically, instead of letting `wxFrame` do it.

Comment: 1)Can I found somewhere the info if it was fixed without compiling lib? I've got some strange compilation errors and I don't want to make angry more.

Comment: 2)You mean using a sizerwhich includes everything else on wxFrame ? Or adding toolbar (??!) to sizer?

Comment: (1) not really, no, you need to compile it but this really shouldn't be a problem. (2) yes, you can add toolbar to the sizer -- in this case do *not* set it as the frame toolbar but just manage it as any other window.

Comment: 1)Compilation takes some time on my PC. :) Can't I ask the dev of the project?
2)You mean to put it f.e. on wxPanel?

Comment: (1) You can ask, but I can't answer because I don't know. (2) Yes, you can make it a child of a wxPanel.